# iterate thrugh values in each columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to iterate through data in a DataFrame, I would like to iterate through all the data in the first column, before moving to the next.

with the code below I get to iterate over the data row by row for all columns

[image]

Instead, I would like to iterate through all the data in the first column before moving to the next.

[image]

```
import time
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('testDATA.csv')

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(row)
    time.sleep(1)
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        print(column)
        time.sleep(1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pandas.DataFrame` itself has [`DataFrame.iteritems()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) method to iterate over all the columns of a dataframe:

```
In [8]: df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2], 'col2': [3, 4]})                                                 

In [9]: for col_name, col_data in df.iteritems(): 
   ...:     print(col_name) 
   ...:     print(col_data.values)   # can be iterated separately 
   ...:                                                                                                     
col1
[1 2]
col2
[3 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DataFrame.transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) an then use your code...

```
import time
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('testDATA.csv')
```

---

```
df=df.T
```

---

```
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    #print(row)
    time.sleep(1)
    for j, column in row.iteritems():
        print(column)
        time.sleep(1)

print(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to rotate the logic. First of all iterate through the items and then again by its items. Examine the following code:

```py
for i, column in df.iteritems():
    for j, row in column.iteritems():
        print(row)
```